# Как в thymeleaf писать по-нормальному?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Вот за что я любил html - он очень не требователен к синтаксису. Забудешь скобку, опечатаешься в слове, не закроешь тэг - браузер по максимуму сам исправит все твои ошибки. А на днях познакомился c Thymeleaf и теперь мне приходится каждый-прекаждый одиночный тэг закрывать вот такой штукой: "/>". И ведь не дай бог не закроешь - словишь -TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document. В связи с этим вопрос: можно ли как-то ослабить правила, и начать писать на html, а не на xhtml?

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать редактор, который понимает xhtml, и подсвечивает неправильные конструкции?

Comment: @VladD, я в Intellig IDEA работаю.

Comment: @Dazar: А он не понимает? Тогда поменяйте его на более подходящий редактор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При конфигурировании templateResolver нужно указать тип шаблона:

```
<property name="templateMode" value="LEGACYHTML5" />
```

Comment: @a_gura, у меня так и есть. Тем не менее он ругается, если, например, написано <input type="text" autofocus/> или <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus">вместо <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus"/>
@Bean(name = "templateResolver")
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver  templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

Comment: А если так?

{<input type="text" autofocus>}

Comment: @Dazar думаю, дело все-таки в `templateMode`. Попробуйте `Legacy HTML5`.

Comment: Ответ поправил.

Comment: @a_gura, заработало. Пришлось правда подключить вот такую штуку, но зато теперь всё хорошо.

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.15</version>
        </dependency>